# imported STL file -> textured added not displayed

Tags: texturing, import, stl

I am new in Blender. I used Blender 2.91.0 under windows 10. I designed a basic cube in Onshape (kind of solidworks software) and exported as STL file. I imported this part in Blender, applied an image texture (in base color) but the texture is not displayed. If I do the same think with the startup cube already created in Blender, It works properly. See below some screenshots. Any ideas why the texture cannot be seen on STL imported part?

[image: two cubes : STL and Blender]

[image: with texture applied]

---

Following your recommendation,  I applied an UV unwrapped and the texture is now displayed but how to have similar pattern that for the other cube?

[image: UV unwrapped]

Comment: STL Files don't have textures or shaders.

Comment: I know that the texture cannot be embedded in STL file that's why I imported first the STL part in Blender AND THEN I added an image texture on the part. The same image texture has been applied on the STL cube and also on the Blender created cube but only the latter works properly. why?

Comment: Have you uv unwrapped the object?

Comment: Following your recommendation,  I applied an UV unwrapped and the texture is now display but how to have similar pattern that for the other cube?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, you should watch this video much better than I can explain https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM 
But at this point I suggest just exporting FBX or .blend with all external files packed.

Comment: thank you Yohello, I will try that!